# Bootstrap left align right-text class on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Using the `text-right` class on my form labels, when going responsive, I want the label to left align so it's top-left instead of top-right, however the change to `text-align:left` does not appear to take effect.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-group > label.text-right {
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">Label</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to use `!important`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't change it.

Comment: I copied your snippet and it worked, try to refresh browser cache via `ctrl` + `f5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap's text alignment classes are *responsive*. You **don't need any extra CSS**.
Use **`text-sm-right text-left`**...

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-sm-right text-left">Label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/djMd492DHA

Comment: This is even better!

Comment: That's way better! It looks like `text-sm-right` wasn't available in Bootstrap 3, so I'll leave my answer for anyone that finds this and is using Bootstrap 3, but this is way easier.

Answer (score 4):

**Note: The accepted answer is best for Bootstrap 4, but the following will work for Bootstrap 3**

That's become `!important` is set on `.text-right`

You can also set `!important`.  I might suggest not using the `.text-right` class and maybe make your own.  Using `!important` to override another `!important` makes me cringe. I wouldn't recommend it, and I would recommend using `!important` as infrequently as possible.  I can understand why Bootstrap uses it here, though.

I'll give you two options.

Here's what you could do:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-group > label.text-right {
    text-align: left !important;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">Label</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I suggest doing:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-group > label.align-label {
    text-align: left;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label align-label">Label</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're right. I'll just make my own class as even `!important` is not producing a result.

Comment: It does in my snippet. It depends where your CSS files are loading as well, and when.